# Populating a CheckListBox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I have a small requirement and i request anyone to help me out by providing the source code for the same.

The requirement is as follows:

Can you please help me as to how to call a stored procedure by passing paramenters and populate a CheckListBox in VB.NET based on the results returned from the stored procedure.

Regards,
George

Comment: @george-trevour ~ I think you have some bad info here George. A) Java != VB.NET ... B) do you mean the CheckBoxList? Check MSDN ... C) What have you tried already? ... D) is this for a winforms or ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

import that namespace and write the following code to some method and change your code According to your Database and Procedure Fields

```
'Set up Connection object and Connection String for a SQL Client
Using SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
   SQLCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server;User ID=User;Password=Password;"
   SQLCon.Open()

   Dim lDataTable As New DataTable
   Using SQLCmdAs New SqlCommand()
     SQLCmd.CommandText = "GetAuthors"  ' Stored Procedure to Call
     SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon

     SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("AuthorName", SqlDbType.VarChar) 

     Dim daPubs As New SqlDataAdapter
     daPubs.SelectCommand = SQLCmd

     daPubs.Fill(lDataTable)
  End Using
End Using

CheckBoxList1.DataSource = lDataTable;
CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ID"
CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

[Using Stored Procedures in Conjuction with DataAdapter](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dclark/UseSPwithDP11282005035417AM/UseSPwithDP.aspx)

[How to call SQL Server stored procedures in ASP.NET by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574)